# FastMM svn version

Tags: delphi, fastmm

I downloaded FastMM through an svn checkout. (instead of stable packaged version)

Can I use it (or is it safe to use) in my release builds?

---

I'm asking this as a seperate question as [Rob Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy) suggested.

Comment: When I mentioned that you could get more points by asking your questions separately, it was predicated on your using the same account to ask all your questions. You can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to ask an admin to merge your accounts into one.

Answer (score 9):

You can, sure, but it is up to you to determine if this build is stable enough for your application.  Pierre does excellent, amazing work, but of course, one should carefully examine and test your application before making such a determination.

Comment: This is about the best answer you're gonna get to this question.  If Pierre was certain it was good enough for an official release version, it would be one already.